# Java 7 Synchronized method seems to allow multiple threads access

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm having a problem with implementing the Synchronized interface on a Java 7 application. I think the problem may be in the fact that I'm instantiating multiple objects with a static final array that is written to in the synchronized method. It appears that the threads are not acknowledging the monitor? Can I even do what I'm trying to do, or do I need some kind of buffer object that has the array and writeIndex incrementer? (If it helps, the code is at https://github.com/dschaper/CS112_Dan_Schaper/tree/master/Week14/Labs and this is not homework, this is just a non-graded lab.)

```java
public class SingleDice extends Dice implements Runnable {
    String threadName;
    private static final int[] valuesArray = new int[9];
    private static int writeIndex = 0;

    public SingleDice(String tName) {
        super(1);
        threadName = tName;
    }

    public synchronized void add(int value) {
        int pos = writeIndex;
        System.out.printf("%s starting sync add(%d), writeIndex = %d\n",
            Thread.currentThread().getName(), value,
            writeIndex);
        valuesArray[pos] = value;
        System.out.printf("%s wrote %d to index %d\n",        
            Thread.currentThread().getName(), value, writeIndex);
        ++writeIndex;
        System.out.printf("Next writeIndex %d\n", writeIndex);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        add(super.Throw());
        }
    }
}

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SyncDiceExecutor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Creating newCachedThreadPool");
    SingleDice SD1 = new SingleDice("SD1");
    SingleDice SD2 = new SingleDice("SD2");
    SingleDice SD3 = new SingleDice("SD3");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executor.execute(SD1);
    System.out.printf("Starting Thread SD1 %s\n", executor.toString());
    executor.execute(SD2);
    System.out.printf("Starting Thread SD2 %s\n", executor.toString());
    executor.execute(SD3);
    System.out.printf("Starting Thread SD3 %s\n", executor.toString());
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.printf("Execeutor shutdown called: %s\n", executor.toString());

    }
}
```

Output

```
Creating newCachedThreadPool
Starting Thread SD1 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@544ec1[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
pool-1-thread-1 starting sync add(4), writeIndex = 0
pool-1-thread-2 starting sync add(4), writeIndex = 0
Starting Thread SD2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@544ec1[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
pool-1-thread-2 wrote 4 to index 0
pool-1-thread-1 wrote 4 to index 0
pool-1-thread-3 starting sync add(4), writeIndex = 1
Next writeIndex 1
pool-1-thread-2 starting sync add(6), writeIndex = 2
Starting Thread SD3 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@544ec1[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
pool-1-thread-2 wrote 6 to index 2
Next writeIndex 3
pool-1-thread-3 wrote 4 to index 2
Next writeIndex 4
Next writeIndex 2
pool-1-thread-3 starting sync add(1), writeIndex = 4
pool-1-thread-2 starting sync add(6), writeIndex = 3
Execeutor shutdown called: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@544ec1[Shutting down, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
pool-1-thread-2 wrote 6 to index 4
Next writeIndex 5
pool-1-thread-3 wrote 1 to index 4
Next writeIndex 6
pool-1-thread-1 starting sync add(3), writeIndex = 4
pool-1-thread-3 starting sync add(1), writeIndex = 6
pool-1-thread-1 wrote 3 to index 6
pool-1-thread-3 wrote 1 to index 6
Next writeIndex 8
Next writeIndex 7
pool-1-thread-1 starting sync add(1), writeIndex = 8
pool-1-thread-1 wrote 1 to index 8
Next writeIndex 9

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SD1, SD2 and SD3 are *different* objects, i.e. they don't share the same monitor. Each object has its own monitor. You could use synchronized(SingleDice.class) {...} if you want to share the monitor across all instances.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So the method is explicitly `public synchronized void add(int value) { synchronized(this) ... }` as I had it coded above? (As @hyde pointed out) I just needed to explicitly change (this) to (SingleDice.class).

Comment: Putting `synchronized` into the method signature essentially does the same as `synchronized(this) {method body}` inside the method. So you can remove the `synchronized` from the signature and add `synchronized(SingleDice.class) { ... }` around the method body.

Comment: `public synchronized void add(int value) {
        synchronized (SingleDice.class){
        int pos = writeIndex;
        valuesArray[pos] = value;
        System.out.printf("%s wrote %d to index %d\n",  (), value, writeIndex);
        ++writeIndex;
        }
    }` Sorry, not sure how to do a code block in a comment

Comment: Yes, and you can remove the `synchronized` keyword from the method signature now to avoid dining philosopher problems.

Comment: Oh! Lightbulb seems to be trying to flicker! I don't need to sync the entire method, just the atomic code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `synchronized` on non-static method synchronizes on `this`, so if you have different objects, they are not mutually exclusive. If you can't use static method (which synchronizes on the class), the solution is to add static lock object and synchronize on that to protect static data.

```
static final Object valueArrayLock = new Object();
```

...

```
// inside a method
synchronized(valueArrayLock) {
    // operate on valueArray
}
```

Note, that if you need to lock this in static methods, use the same static lock object, instead of making the static method synchronized (or see the other answer about using the class object for locking).

Comment: The object is not needed, you can use `ClassName.class`. That's a static object in every class. This is even compatible to synchronizing static methods because it's exactly what they do.

Comment: @fpw I prefer the clarity of explicit, descriptively named lock object. It's also easier/cleaner, if another lock object needs to be added. But, matter of style.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to point out that this breaks compatibility with synchronized static methods - you could easily run into a dining philosopher problem if you mix both styles.

Comment: @fpw Ah, yeah, good point. Added a paragraph about needing to use the same lock object in static methods too.